# FreeSwitch SIP user auto creation issue

Tags: freeswitch

FreeSwitch 1.2 have default users 1000-1019 with 1234 password. If I want to make a new user, I need to create a XML file for 1 user. I cannot create XML files for each users.

Here is one of SIP address. 5162867094@domain.com I would like to create a account with 10 number characters with some password.

- Auto Register without creating a new XML file.
- Number will be 5162867094 like this. (10 digit numbers)
- It would be better if I can put password for each account.

How can I make above Dialplan using few XML codes? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already got the recommendation to use mod_xml_curl in another stackexchange question. You just need to read the mod_xml_curl documentation again :)

Comment: Thanks. I've read mod_xml_curl page. I thought there should be a way using XML file... like group...

Comment: You can configure multiple users in the same XML file. If you look into the content of default FreeSWITCH configuration, you would notice `include` statements. You can replace these includes with actual XML and keep all users in the same file. Also see here: http://txlab.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/minimal-freeswitch-configuration/

Comment: another problem.. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748202/freeswitch-it-doesnt-connect-mysql-database-using-xml-mod-curl

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the mod_xml_curl suggestion -- or doing the same with lua - I have just one thing to tell you:

You don't need one FILE per user. You can list multiple users in the same XML file (followed by a 'reloadxml')

Comment: great answer..  I could save user data in one xml file. Thank you.

Comment: I think the best would be if you read the book: http://www.packtpub.com/freeswitch-1-2/book