# FreeSwitch - It doesn't connect MySQL database using xml_mod_curl

Tags: freeswitch

After install FreeSwitch, I tried to connect user account using xml_mod_curl. I followed below instruction to connect MySQL database.

http://saevolgo.blogspot.kr/2012/07/freeswitch-with-sip-users-in-mysql-mod.html

I could see that it actually read XML to sign in SIP account with 1000-1019 username. However, it doesn't look like it connects MySQL database. I failed to sign in new user and new password that is saved in MySQL column.

here is global_defines.php

```
if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == basename(__FILE__)) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

/**
 * Defines the default dsn for the FS_PDO class
 */
define('DEFAULT_DSN', 'mysql:dbname=FS_DB;host=127.0.0.1');
/**
 * Defines the default dsn login for the PDO class
 */
define('DEFAULT_DSN_LOGIN', 'root');
/**
 * Defines the default dsn password for the PDOclass
 */
define('DEFAULT_DSN_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
/**
 * Generic return success
 */
define('FS_CURL_SUCCESS', 0);
/**
 * Generic return success
 */
define('FS_SQL_SUCCESS', '00000');
/**
 * Generic return warning
 */
define('FS_CURL_WARNING', 1);
/**
 * Generic return critical
 */
define('FS_CURL_CRITICAL', 2);

/**
 * determines how the error handler handles warnings
 */
define('RETURN_ON_WARN', true);

/**
 * Determines whether or not users should be domain specific
 * If GLOBAL_USERS is true, user info will be returned for whatever
 * domain is passed.....
 * NOTE: using a1 hashes will NOT work with this setting
 */
define('GLOBAL_USERS', false);
```

The instruction article was written 2 years ago. It seems like there should be one more option to turn on My-SQL connection. Did I missing something?